# CSS. background-image

Tags: css

Всем привет, можете, пожалуйста, помочь.
Не помещается картинка, а именно её правая часть.
Секция first_block(её фоновое изображение).

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}

.first_block {
 background-image: url('img/photo.png');
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1024px;
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Waxom</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Waxom.Landing page.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="first_block">
 <header class="header">
  <div class="section_start"> 
      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logos.png">
        </div>
        <nav class="navigation">
         <ul class="menu">
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About us</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>Features</li>
          <li>Blog</li>
          <li>Pricing</li>
          <li>Shortcodes</li>
          <li>Contact</li> 
         </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="icons">
         <img src="">
         <img src="">
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Добавьте картинку в пример.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513: говорят же Вам - не помещается - потому и добавить не может)))

Comment: Не могу прикрепить, объём слишком большой

Comment: @ГригорийКалашников откройте Paint и уменьшите

Comment: @ГригорийКалашников и да, если её объём слишком большой, то ставить объёмную картинку на фон — это крайне хреновая идея и лучи ненависти от пользователей мобильного интернета. Рекомендую вам переосмыслить то, что вы хотите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}

.first_block {
 background-image: url('https://cortexonemsedu.azureedge.net/assets/hero-remote-learning-surface-1399/1/hero_remote-learning_surface_1399.jpg');
 background-size: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 1024px;
 background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Waxom</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Waxom.Landing page.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="first_block">
 <header class="header">
  <div class="section_start"> 
      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logos.png">
        </div>
        <nav class="navigation">
         <ul class="menu">
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About us</li>
          <li>Portfolio</li>
          <li>Features</li>
          <li>Blog</li>
          <li>Pricing</li>
          <li>Shortcodes</li>
          <li>Contact</li> 
         </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="icons">
         <img src="">
         <img src="">
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' А если так background-size: auto; ? Могут быть какие-то проблемы с contain?

Comment: @Sevastopol', почему `contain` плохая идея?

Comment: @Sevastopol', а ну так-то да, думал что-то с свойством не то))

Comment: @Sevastopol' Я чуть сума не сошел размышляя почему contain это bad practice :D